# Does VxWorks has a stack canary mechanism?

Tags: stack-overflow

I'm trying to understand if VxWorks has the ability to support stack canary protection. I couldn't find any info on that.

Comment: Please see the security section in the [official product sheet for VxWorks](https://www.windriver.com/products/vxworks/datasheet) for all the security features available. If you don't see it mentioned there then it likely isn't there.